# Print result of array is hard to figure out

Tags: java

I'm new to Java here. I've been working on this exercise and came across this interesting problem that I'm trying to figure out.

I'm confused on how it prints 2,4,4 and 2,4,8. I know how the 1's and 2,3,4 works.

Here's the print result.

1
, 2
, 3
, 4

1
, 2
, 4
, 4

1
, 2
, 4
, 8

I have tried checking how array[idx] works by printing it (not in the code btw) and I understand that in the first loop, array[idx] will be 4 because the index[2] is 3, 3-1 = 2, 2*2 = 4.

However, I'm confused about the second loop, where the array[idx] is 8. I thought the index[3] is 4, 4-1 = 3, 3*2 = 6?

Here's the code.

```
public static void main (String[] args){
    int[] v = {1,2,3,4};
    print(v);
    fiddle(v, v[2]-1);
    print(v);
    fiddle(v, v[3]-1); 
    print(v);
}

public static void fiddle(int[] array, int idx) {
    array[idx] = array[idx - 1] * 2; 
}

public static void print(int[] array) {
    System.out.println(array[0]);
    for (int i = 1; i < array.length; i++){
        System.out.println(", " + array[i]);
    }
    System.out.println(); 
}
```

I just want to know how fiddle and print methods work together to get the result of 2, 4, 4 and 2, 4, 8.

Comment: Did you step through each line of code in a debugger?

Comment: You could step through the code with a debugger and look at the values to get a grasp of what's happening. To get you started though have a look at `fiddle(v, v[2]-1);`: here `v[2]-1` will use the value at index 2 which is 3 and subtract 1, so the value 2 will be passed as the index to `fiddle`. That method will then set the element at index 2 to 2 times the value of the element at index 1 (due to `idx - 1`) which is 2*2 = 4. Thus the value at index 2 is changed from 3 to 4. The same happens for the next call to `fiddle` just with different indices.

Comment: @OldProgrammer Yes, I went through the debugger using BlueJ but it's still not clear enough for me.

Comment: "I thought the index[3] is 4, 4-1 = 3, 3*2 = 6?" you missed the fact that at `3*2` what is multiplied isn't `idx*2` but `array[idx-1]*2`. So for `idx=3` it is like `array[3-1]*2` and when `array={1,2,4,4}` array[3-1] is array[2] which is 4. So you end up with 4*2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is because each use of the fiddle method starts with the previous state of the array. You are not resetting the array back to its original state before calling fiddle.

So in the case of your 3rd fiddle call, it is using [1,2,4,4] where the 3rd index - 1 = 4 * 2 which is 8

As others have said in comments, debugging this would have saved you a question. But since you are new to Java you may not have known that which is OK. I recommend learning how to use the debugger in whichever IDE you use.

Comment: Took me hours to understand it but thanks to everyone, it's very clear to me now. I'm using BlueJ's debugger and I tried looking into the array and it does change from the first and second fiddle call.